# Changing self.variables inside __exit__ method of Context Managers

Tags: python, pandas, with-statement, contextmanager

First thing first, the title is very unclear, however nothing better sprang to my mind. I'll ellaborate the problem in more detail.

I've found myself doing this routine a lot with `pandas` dataframes. I need to work for a while with only the part(some columns) of the DataFrame and later I want to add those columns back. The an idea came to my mind = Context Managers. But I am unable to come up with the correct implementation (if there is any..).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class ProtectColumns:
    def __init__(self, df, protect_cols=[]):

        self.protect_cols = protect_cols
        # preserve a copy of the part we want to protect
        self.protected_df = df[protect_cols].copy(deep=True)
        # create self.df with only the part we want to work on
        self.df = df[[x for x in df.columns if x not in protect_cols]]

    def __enter__(self):
        # return self, or maybe only self.df?
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # btw. do i need *args and **kwargs here?
        # append the preserved data back to the original, now changed
        self.df[self.protect_cols] = self.protected_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # testing
    # create random DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=list("ABCD"))
    # uneccessary step
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(100 * x))
    # show it
    print(df)
    # work without cols A and B
    with ProtectColumns(df, ["A", "B"]) as PC:
        # make everything 0
        PC.df = PC.df.applymap(lambda x: 0)
    # this prints the expected output
    print(PC.df)
```

However, say I don't want to use PC.df onwards, but df. I could just do df = PC.df, or make a copy inside `with` or after that. But is is possible to handle this inside e.g. the `__exit__` method?

```
# unchanged df
print(df)
with ProtectColumns(df, list("AB")) as PC:
    PC.applymap(somefunction)

# df is now changed
print(df)
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? The definition is [in the data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__), which tell you what arguments to expect.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. It sort of works, but I am not sure you've understood the "concept" I've tried to explain. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Then [edit] to explain more clearly. What does *"sort of works"* mean, exactly? What precisely do you still need help with?

Comment: The last bit of code example in my question is not working, but it shows how I would like the context manager to work. The DataFrame `df` is not changed in the last print (although the comment says so)..